# Changing a game server platform

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, xna

I'm developing a small multiplayer game, and currently the game server runs in a c# console application.

This limits me because:

- the server gets stuck whenever I even start a text select in the console. If I even accidentally touch the console, the server gets stuck and I'm left shocked that the client is stuck somewhy, whereas it gets timed-out as soon as I right click the console and the select is canceled
- I'm limited with supplying user input to the server. Say, I want to implement server commands, I have a great system I've written that handles pub-sub messages that I can use, and I just don't have any way to easily send those messages, since the server is console based and I can't rely on console input, when there's a lot of output to the console, and the client (which can publish those messages as well) is XNA base, and there's no easy way to implement a console on the client side (which would be an awesome thing to do, and would somehow solve some of my problems if I found a good library for XNA consoles).

I have several options to choose from -

- WPF - I can write the server in WPF instead of a ConsoleApplication. This would give me somehow nice GUI, and it would be relatively easy to integrate since the majority of the code is a library and I wouldn't even need to export events, since I would be able to use my pub-sub system for the events.
- Web - I have this picture in my mind - I run an executable which starts a local server, and it would just run in the background, people would be able to connect regularly, but I would be able to access a web page, and control the server through it. It would of course be a different port than the game server itself (I assume), and I would be able to control the server (send commands, kick players, restart rounds, and so on) through it.

What I'm here for, is for your suggestions, first of all. What do you find more suitable, pros and cons.
And if we're talking about a web-based server, what's the most standard way of doing that? I mean... mostly for raising a server, and how the website would communicate with it.

Thanks for reading, and thanks in advance for the advises!

Comment: i think this will burn down here .. opinion base and all ... having said that, i didn't expect an issue with the console tbh. Chuck all your logic in a dll , and then you can run it from whatever you want (web/wpf/console)

Comment: Just repeat same as previous answer. Isolate your server logic and publish server API for managing and then you will able to run it, for example, in separate thread or as windows service with any GUI (console/wpf/web)

Comment: All consoles stick if you start highlighting things  Just run it as a service if you dont want that, and output to text file..  That involves very little code change.

Comment: In fact, the majority of the server is in the dll, I just don't export any events, cause I use the pub-sub system for stuff like that. If I export the pubsub system in the dlls, can I use it anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would probably be to use something like [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org) (which is super simple to use) to process REST commands. You can add a Nancy webhost project to your solution and run it alongside your server, reusing your pub/sub architecture. Bonus, you can then use Nancy for certain client services that may not work as well on the server.

This is in fact similar to what we're doing with out XNA game, except Nancy also talks directly to clients, alongside the server, to serve up certain cpu or database bound data that isn't performance critical. We use redis to handle the pub/sub communication between the Nancy hosts and server instances.