# Creating a server and site with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, server, xna

following [my previous post about my game server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463058/changing-a-game-server-platform?noredirect=1#comment66247851_39463058), I've decided that I want to create a web-based server, and not a WPF one.

Currently, the server is a console application. I run the server, it has a TcpListener, and I interact with TcpClients, and the only real console-y thing I have, is a bunch of `Console.WriteLine`s that I intend to get rid of. The server itself is part of a class library, which contains all the server logic, so that it'll be easy to wrap it in whatever platform I need.

Say I have a library with all my `server-side` logic, and I want the `GUI` of the server to be a `web client`, while still having a server that runs in the background and keeps the game running - How do I do that with ASP.NET?

Since all my code is `C#`, it's natural that I would pick ASP.NET, and use `MVC` with `Razor`, allowing me to use my original classes as data in the website.

I can handle the website part of the ASP.NET, but what I need advice with is how I create a server that acts like my previous one `(runs in the background, has some sort of GUI, for input, commands and etc)`, and also has a website as the GUI.

Thanks in advance!

for reference, all my `ConsoleApplication` code is [here](https://github.com/gioragutt/xna-ecs/blob/master/XnaTry/ConsoleServer/Program.cs), showing just how little the platform that runs the server has to do.

And regardless, [this is the link to my game code](https://github.com/gioragutt/xna-ecs), if anyone is interested. I'm always interested in opinions and constructive criticism!

Comment: This question will most likely be deemed off-topic on SO. You're better off zeroing on a particular implementation and asking something specific about it. [Where should I ask software architecture / design questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124867/where-should-i-ask-software-architecture-design-questions)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) is an article about self hosting webapi and static files in a console application using Owin, no support for MVC.  [Asp.Net Core](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS) has a similar work flow (though it's not called Owin anymore), and MVC is available.  Asp.Net Core apps are actually self hosted in a console application using Kestrel.  When you host asp.net core in IIS all IIS does is act as a proxy.